# ASP.NET Active Directory roles - managing overlapping roles

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I'm probably missing something easy here, but I've never done this before, so I thought I'd ask the Stackers.

I've implemented Windows Authentication on my ASP.NET app (IIS 7.5). I have rules for both the application (system.web) and IIS (system.webServer) that deny anonymous users, deny built in admins, and allow members of "Demolitions Repayment".

The trouble is, I am a built in admin AND in "Demolitions Repayment", but I'm locked out. Is it a matter of precedence?

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/errors/Unknown.htm" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    <deny roles="BUILTIN\Administrators" />
        <allow roles="gc\Demolitions Repayment" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
    <add accessType="Deny" roles="BUILTIN\Administrators" />
            <add accessType="Allow" roles="gc\Demolitions Repayment" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try denying all users (authenticated and not authenticated) and then grant only a certain role:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?,*" />
        <allow roles="gc\Demolitions Repayment" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <add accessType="Deny" users="?,*" />
            <add accessType="Allow" roles="gc\Demolitions Repayment" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: The order of operations is important, the first line of deny=?,*  is by definition seeing you as masked by * and denied. Try swapping the Allow and Deny entries.